# »mit nach Hause nehmen« – grammatikalische Analyse

Tags: modal-verb, separable-verb

Als Muttersprachler habe ich kein Problem mit dem Satz

> Das will ich mit nach Hause nehmen.

Eine Bekannte, die Deutsch lernt, hat mich nun gefragt, warum dieser Satz richtig ist, und nicht etwa

> Das will ich nach Hause mitnehmen.

Nach kurzer [Recherche](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modalverb) habe ich nur die Regel gefunden, dass in einem Satz mit Modalverb das Vollverb im Infinitiv vorkommt. Das würde der zweiten Version entsprechen. Aber ich bin mir sehr sicher, dass die erste Version zumindest ebenso korrekt ist, wenn nicht sogar die bevorzugte Variante.

Gibt es eine Regel, die es erlaubt trennbare Verben in solchen Konstruktionen zu trennen? Hat es etwas mit der Trennung von Verben in Sätzen wie folgendem zu tun?

> Das nehme ich nach Hause mit.

Wenn ja, wäre folgender Satz grammatikalisch korrekt? Er hört sich für mich falsch an:

> Das will ich mit als Geschenk nehmen.

Comment: Ich habe Zweifel, ob es sich bei *mit nach Hause nehmen* um ein trennbares Verb handelt.. Ich halte das für die gleiche Kategorie wie: *Kannst Du das mit einstecken?* Während im letzten Beispiel offensichtlich etwas wie *mit den anderen Sachen* gemeint ist, fällt mir in der ursprünglichen Frage nur ein weggefallenes *mir* ein.

Comment: @guidot: Ohne Modalverb wäre es `Das nehme ich mit nach Hause` bzw. `Das nehme ich nach Hause mit`. Sind das nicht beides getrennte "mitnehmen"? Gehört das "mit" im ersten Satz etwa nicht zum Verb?

Comment: Gute Frage. Für deine These spricht, dass *Das nehme ich nach Hause* nicht geht.

Comment: Allerdings fällt mir gerade auf, dass es möglich ist, im ersten Satz ein weiteres `mit` hinzuzufügen, also `Das nehme ich mit nach Hause mit`. Daher denke ich, dass @guidot doch Recht hatte! Dass es sich also in diesem Fall nicht um ein trennbares Verb handelt, sondern um die Präposition `mit` und dem Verb `nehmen`.

Comment: "Das will ich nach Hause mitnehmen" ist ebenfalls korrekt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Des Rätsels Lösung: Es sind zwei verschiedene Sätze mit zwei verschiedenen Verben und zwei verschiedenen Präpositionalkonstruktionen.

> Das will ich nach Hause mitnehmen.

Dieser Satz hat das trennbare Verb *mitnehmen*. Der Ort, wohin es mitgenommen wird, ist *nach Hause*. Man könnte ihn auch ohne Modalverb formulieren, dann wird daraus:

> Das nehme ich nach Hause mit.

Wichtig: Ein trennbares Verb kann es nur sein wenn (von wenigen Ausnahmen wie erweiterten Infinitiven abgesehen) alle Satzbestandteile außer Subjekt zwischen dem konjugierten Verb und dem abtrennbaren Partikel im Hauptfeld auftauchen. Sobald das *nach Hause* hinter das *mit* verschwindet, ist diese Bedingung nicht mehr erfüllt. Daher rührt die zweite Variante:

> Das will ich mit nach Hause nehmen.

Oder ohne Modalverb:

> Das nehme ich mit nach Hause.

Hier ist *nehmen* das Verb und die Präpositionalkonstruktion ist *mit nach Hause*.

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl betont das Verb *mitnehmen* mehr, dass man, was auch immer es ist, an sich nimmt und an (irgend-) einen anderen Ort transportiert. *Mit nach Hause* würde eher betonen, dass man zusammen mit sich selbst das Mitgenommene an einen bestimmten anderen Ort (nach Hause) bringt.

*Mit als Geschenk* funktioniert deswegen nicht wirklich. Was wiederum geht wäre:

> Das will ich mit ins Geschenk einpacken.

Answer (score 2):

**Both forms are correct.**

The dependency of "mit" to "nehmen" does not dissolve when its proximity to the verb is changed.

Language is dynamic and has many acceptable forms. English matured with the second construct you mentioned. The former became obsolete in English as English moved towards  a *Subject - Verb - Object (SVO)* sentence structure.

> Das will ich mit nach Hause nehmen.

- "I want **to take** it home **with** me."

> "Das will ich mit als Geschenk nehmen."

- "I want **to take it** [**with** me] as a gift."

You will notice that although English separates "with" from "to take", it is nonetheless a dependency of "to take" i.e. the verb is "to take with",  not "to take away". Here is guidot's remark illustrated quite well. I think there is some overlap in the functions of "with" as a preposition and as a verbal modifier which allows for greater flexibility.

You will also notice that English follows a *Subject - Verb - Object (SVO)* construction, while German often has a *Subject - Object - Verb (SOV)* construction (closely related to Old High German).

When you hear something that "sounds" correct, but you can not discount the other as incorrect, you must consider that phrasal norms, like word choice, are influenced by frequency of use.

e.g. English also provides other acceptable forms with separable verbs:

- "His mother told him to turn the lights off."
- "His mother told him to turn off the lights."

---

**Notes**
By acceptable I am referring to an arbitrarily large collective group of people—a community—in which a given form is common.

Comment: Just to clarify: your answer is "we use it that way, so it is correct" ?

Comment: @M.Herzkamp That is oversimplified, but I suppose ultimately anything in language acceptable because it is used that way (somebody is writing the rules down either prescriptively or descriptively!). Understanding my analysis would be a better way to understand my answer: Floating verbal modifiers/phrasal verb complements are permitted in German. Another reason for the large flexibility in your particular example is the overlap of the syntactic functionality of "mit".

Comment: "Floating verbal modifiers/phrasal verb complements are permitted in German." Tbh, this is the first time I see someone state it. Do you have any sources backing up that this is a rule? Online references would be enough.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp Sure. Working at the moment, but I am sure I can get something to support that claim later